# Can I use core data for my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, model

I am making an app which shows serval forms. The forms data will be saved in the local and uploaded in the future. The sources code was already there and the models are using core data.

Now our client challenges us. They want to add some new forms without changing the app. The models and layouts of the forms will be totally different.

My idea is creating a XML format which stores a form configuration. Forms are to be created and loaded onto the server.

My Question is can I use core data to do this, or I have to use SQLite(FMDB).
Can anyone give me some suggestion? Sincere thanks!!!

---

My Question may not clear

If we use core data, we can create the model class first. 
But the issue now is the model is dynamic, it will be changed by different forms(xml).
Is core data available?

Comment: if the model is dynamic and you have not too many relationships among the "entities", you could work with `.plist` without any pain. you can use the predicates to filter your datas as well. but everything depends on how huge the amount of data you like to store... these details will define the final type of your model. however, the model is independent of any other layers (if the code pattern built correctly), and you can change the model layer anytime when you experience any performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to use core data as I find it easy and less lines to code and hence less mess in the code.
Although its upto you what you want to use, any database(core data or SQLite) will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for Core Data because it is pretty easy to do and you will save your time to do that if you want any example then i have one good link which will teach you that how to do that Core Data.
this is the link where u can check the way of doing.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: the issue is different forms using different models.